# Picture not showing

Tags: php, html, database, image, photo

I have used the filedisplay.php?id= method for displaying a product on which user chooses. The picture is displayed on the index from database but is not showing on filedisplay.php :(

My filedisplay.php

```
    <?php
include 'fileconstant.php';
 // just so we know it is broken
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 // some basic sanity checks
 if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
     //connect to the db
     $link = mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$pass")
     or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

     // select our database
     mysql_select_db("$db") or die(mysql_error());

     // get the image from the db
     $sql = "SELECT photo FROM products WHERE id=" .$_GET['id'] . ";";

     // the result of the query
     $result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());

     // set the header for the image
     header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
     echo mysql_result($result, 0);

     // close the db link
     mysql_close($link);
 }
 else {
     echo 'Please use a real id number';
 }
?>
```

---

This is the problem, below in the picture!

Comment: First check whether *photo* column of your table contains just the image name or the full path of the image, you need to have full path of the image to be displayed on the screen.

Comment: Yes its correct :/